# Youtube video layout and autoplaying issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

I have 4 embedded youtube videos in a simple page. One is on the center top, the left one is flipped vertically, the right is flipped vertically too and the bottom one is upside down and centered. The only issue I am having is that its not auto playing as soon as I load the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>HTML5 Face Detection</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-color:#000000 
}

#topVid, #leftVid, #rightVid, #bottomVid {



}

#topVid {
    width: 576px;
    height: 324px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg); /* Firefox */
}

#flexContainer {
    width: 1224px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;;
}

#leftVid {

    width: 324px;
    height: 576px;
    background-color: #ACACAC;
    transform:  rotateY(180deg);  
}

#leftVidTransform {

    transform:  rotate(90deg);  
}

#centerBox {

    width: 576px;
    height: 576px;
}

#rightVidTransform {

    transform:  rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top: 250px;  
}

#rightVid {

    width: 324px;
    height: 576px;
    background-color: #333;
    transform:  rotateY(180deg);  
}

#bottomVid {
    width: 576px;
    height: 324px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #000;
     transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:rotateX(180deg); /* Firefox */
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<div id="topVid"><iframe width="576" height="324" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eYR1TqYGNls?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

<div id="flexContainer">
<div id="leftVid"><div id="leftVidTransform"><iframe width="576" height="324" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eYR1TqYGNls?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
<div id="centerBox"></div>
<div id="rightVid"><div id="rightVidTransform"><iframe width="576" height="324" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eYR1TqYGNls?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>

</div>

<div id="bottomVid"><iframe width="576" height="324" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eYR1TqYGNls?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>


</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I added `autoplay=1` but no success. The other option I tried was with Youtube's API iframe script and removing the `<iframe>` from the `<div>` section.

I used the following:

```
<script src="//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

    <script>
        /**
         * Put your video IDs in this array
         */
        var videoIDs = [
            'eYR1TqYGNls'
        ];

        var topVid, currentVideoId = 0;
        var leftVid, currentVideoId = 0;
        var rightVid, currentVideoId = 0;
        var bottomVid, currentVideoId = 0;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            topVid = new YT.Player('topVid', {
                height: '576',
                width: '324',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });

            leftVid = new YT.Player('leftVid', {
                height: '576',
                width: '324',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });

            rightVid = new YT.Player('rightVid', {
                height: '576',
                width: '324',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });

            bottomVid = new YT.Player('bottomVid', {
                height: '576',
                width: '324',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
        }

        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                currentVideoId++;
                if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
                    topVid.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
                    leftVid.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
                    rightVid.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
                    bottomVid.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

As soon as I load the page, all 4 videos run automatically but the top and bottom are align to the far left corner and each side video are still vertical but the videos are played in portrait mode.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The type of player that you're using can also affect how videos are displayed. Please try using Flash Player 10.1 or higher if you're still using a different player.

As suggested in [YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference),

> **The end user must have Flash Player 10.1 or higher installed to view everything correctly.** Because of this requirement, we suggest using [SWFObject](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject) to embed the SWF and detect the user's Flash Player version.
>
> In addition, any HTML page that contains the YouTube player must implement a JavaScript function named `onYouTubePlayerReady`. The API will call this function when the player is fully loaded and the API is ready to receive calls.
>
> Embedded players must have a viewport that is at least 200px by 200px. If the player displays controls, it must be large enough to fully display the controls without shrinking the viewport below the minimum size. We recommend 16:9 players be at least 480 pixels wide and 270 pixels tall.